# Jmeter 5.3 Gettting Standard Deviation from Report

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to find out if it is possible to get Jmeter to generate standard deviations in its report WITHOUT THE GUI! (<<< Important!). Script based ONLY. I have perused the Internets and most Jmeter information is long since out of date, going back to 2007-2017.

It seems Jmeter has come along way since then incorporating most of the "plugins". I am running JMeter 5.3.
I basically generate tests with

```
jmeter -t test.jmx -l results.csv -jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

Then, as per the documentation I run,

```
jmeter -g results.csv -o report
```

But it seems options to give this command are not plentiful.

This command invocation generates an html site, and it generates a`report/statistics.json` file. However, this file merely contains elements of the "AggregateReport", which are

```
{
    "transaction" : "Total",
    "sampleCount" : 1000,
    "errorCount" : 0,
    "errorPct" : 0.0,
    "meanResTime" : 42.56400000000011,
    "medianResTime" : 37.0,
    "minResTime" : 31.0,
    "maxResTime" : 1327.0,
    "pct1ResTime" : 49.0,
    "pct2ResTime" : 64.0,
    "pct3ResTime" : 95.93000000000006,
    "throughput" : 20.10777768840988,
    "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 17.002539863669266,
    "sentKBytesPerSec" : 6.8610525856088636
  }
```

which does **NOT** include the "Standard Deviation". I am at a loss of "Why not?", but that is another question.

I know people will tell me to add a "SummaryReport" Listener, but that only seems to be useful in the GUI, and this approach MUST be scripted based. I need to be able to read the results out of a file sometime long after the run has completed.

I cannot seem to find the any options to give Jmeter to generate a report that lists the Standard Deviation, or even to generate a file containing a "SummaryReport" in addition to the "AggregateReport".

It appears the only report that is generated is this deficient "AggregateReport".

Any insight?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of those JMeter plugins you mention provides a command line tool to write the "AggregateReport" to a CSV file:

`JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --plugin-type AggregateReport --input-jtl results.csv --generate-csv aggregate_report.csv`

This requires the following three plugins to be installed:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-cmd
- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-synthesis
- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-filterresults

Command line options are listed here: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/

Both the `AggregateReport` and the `SynthesisReport` include standard deviation.

Comment: I apologize. I down-voted this because it would not generate the right stuff from jmeter. It took a while to get plugins installed correctly, which I have to script.